# LinkageError using database-migration plugin (loader previously initialted for a different type)

Tags: grails, database-migration

i get a weird error when trying to use database-migration plugin 1.3.6 with the command line

```
grails --stacktrace dbm-generate-gorm-changelog changelog.groovy
```

Error is

```
Error Error executing script DbmGenerateGormChangelog: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/management/MBeanServer" (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/management/MBeanServer"
```

It only happens when i try to execute this goal non in test or production (embedded tomcat) mode.

I've tried other versions of the plugin with the same end.

I really found the error too cryptic and not sure what is happening under the hoods or how to start fixint this,

Stacktrace is as follows:

```
Error executing script DbmGenerateGormChangelog: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/management/MBeanServer"
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/management/MBeanServer"
        at org.springframework.jmx.support.JmxUtils.locateMBeanServer(JmxUtils.java:111)
        at org.springframework.jmx.support.JmxUtils.locateMBeanServer(JmxUtils.java:76)
        at org.springframework.jmx.support.JmxUtils$locateMBeanServer.call(Unknown Source)
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:754)
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:584)
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:527)
        at _GrailsBootstrap$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsBootstrap.groovy:40)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at _GrailsBootstrap$_run_closure6.doCall(_GrailsBootstrap.groovy:64)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
        at _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy:25)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
        at DbmGenerateGormChangelog$_run_closure1.doCall(DbmGenerateGormChangelog:23)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
```

Comment: _asked 19 hours ago and no response or comment?_  well I am saying grails community is dying. k try adding the  `--verbose` option to your command to see detailed error message.

Comment: Have you ever found out the reason for this? I'm getting the same behavior but have no clue what could have changed regarding my environment as it was working without problems before...

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record: the issue for me was that mx4j was included as dependency via jets3t-plugin. mx4j seems to bring its own `javax/management/MBeanServer` interface that conflicts with the `javax/management/MBeanServer` provivded via the Java SDK/JRE.
Excluding mx4j fixed the issue for me:

`compile 'net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:0.9.3', {
  excludes 'mx4j'
}`